# Skip Integration Tests Using Grails Maven Plugin

Tags: maven, grails, integration-testing

I am using Grails 2.1.0 and Maven 2.1.1. When running the command `mvn clean install` to generate an EAR file Maven runs the unit tests without any issue, besides running them twice, then runs the integration tests. When it gets to the integration test phase it throws an error `Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver'`.

Unit and integration tests all pass when run through Grails, and if I build the ear using the `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` flag it builds without errors and the resulting EAR deploys to the server fine.

I am upgrading this project from 1.3.7 and that version did not run the integration tests while building. It also only ran the unit tests once, but from what I've read doing it twice is a known part of the grails-maven plugin. Below is the pom that I am using.

```
<properties>
    <grails.version>2.1.0</grails.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.6</slf4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
        <artifactId>grails-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${grails.version}</version>
        <exclusions>                
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            </exclusion>            
        </exclusions>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
        <artifactId>grails-plugin-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${grails.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>                    

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>resources</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>                    

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>webxml</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>    

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
    <artifactId>grails-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>${grails.version}</version>       
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>${grails.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement />

    <plugins>
        <!-- Disables the Maven surefire plugin for Grails applications, as we have our own test runner -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>surefire-it</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>plugins</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*</include>
                        </includes>
                        <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
            <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${grails.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Whether for Fork a JVM to run Grails commands -->
                <fork>false</fork>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>init</goal>
                        <goal>maven-clean</goal>
                        <goal>validate</goal>
                        <goal>config-directories</goal>
                        <goal>maven-compile</goal>
                        <goal>maven-test</goal>
                        <goal>maven-war</goal>
                        <goal>maven-functional-test</goal> 
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have tried removing the `maven-functional-test` goal, as well as the entire executions section but run into the same issue either way. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

I tried using the maven failsafe plugin http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html

And adding to my pom.xml...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration>
      <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But mvn clean install still runs functional-tests. Don't know why grails is so stubborn.

I'm really just concerned with skipping grails-maven-functional tests, maybe for your case you could try:

```
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
```

Finally found a work around to skip grails-maven-functional-test if anyone stumbles upon this article. It requires maven 2.2 or above and adding this to your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
    <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${grails.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-maven-functional-test</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```